# angular,button click function from .ts variable

Tags: button, angular-material, angular8

How to create a button from a variable content into my component.html with details setted into `.ts` file?

### .ts

```
doStuff(anArg: string){
  alert(anArg)
}


buildItems(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arg1 = 'something_' + i
        items.push({
            onClick: 'doStuff(' + arg1 + ')',
            buttonTxt: 'button_txt, arg1:' + arg1
        })
    }
}//end function
```

### component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let lItem of items">
    <button ng-click="lItem.onClick">
        {{lItem.buttonTxt}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Doesn't work, the generated code is simply: `ng-click="lItem.onClick"` and any of `[ng-click]="lItem.onClick"` or `ng-click="{{lItem.onClick}}"` gives me a compilation error

[Here a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-custom-svg-icon-z7hqms)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an invalid syntax for Angular 2+.

Actually, you should do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let lItem of items">
    <button (click)="lItem.onClick()">
        {{lItem.buttonTxt}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Also you are defining a string inside your onClick property of item object. You should instead use a function:

```
buildItems(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arg1 = 'something_' + i
        items.push({
            onClick: () => doStuff(arg1),
            buttonTxt: 'button_txt, arg1:' + arg1
        })
    }
}//end function
```

Comment: I added a stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-custom-svg-icon-z7hqms

Comment: `onClick()` with parenthesis will give you a `ERROR
Error: _v.context.$implicit.onClick is not a function`

Comment: It's not onClick, it's just click

Comment: `lItem.onClick` is a variable setted into .ts file thats the goal. Even with `<button (click)="lItem.onClick">` it doesn't work either, see my stackblitz

Comment: Still like your code will be wrong. Where is defined doStuff function?

Comment: Into my `.ts` Added to the example, and buildItems called from an Api for example, whatever trigger

Comment: Thx for your help, I finally got a solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my question was following

1. enclose the function onClick property into a function object into .ts
2. button click event as pointed out by @Elias-Soares has to be `(click)`
3. Finally the `(click)="lItem.onClick()"` syntax triggers the onClick function and not property
4. Note that the doStuff declaration has to be done **into the same component.ts** file not into the `app.component.ts` as it doesn't seem to work

### .ts

```
doStuff(anArg: string){
  alert(anArg)
}


buildItems(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arg1 = 'something_' + i
        items.push({
            onClick: () => { do_stuff('someCustomArgs: ' + arg1) }, // enclose the function onClick property into a function object
            buttonTxt: 'button_txt, arg1:' + arg1
        })
    }
}//end function
```

### component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let lItem of items">
    <button (click)="lItem.onClick()"> <!-- as when parenthesis are given a function call is triggered, otherwise its a property -->
        {{lItem.buttonTxt}}
    </button>
</div>
```